# HTML5 game based on drag and drop

Tags: html, canvas, game-engine, kineticjs, drag-and-drop

I'm building an HTML5 game based on a drag and drop but i'd like to make the object moving automatically, since i'm not using canvas, is there any alternative i can use to the kinetic.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A good alternative to canvas is RaphaelJS.**

This library allows you to define objects and animate them on the screen.

It has many features that are useful in game building:

- automatic animation of CSS attributes.
- built in drag-drop.
- mouse and touch (!) event handling.
- built in hit-testing.
- compatible with older browsers (yes, talking about you internet explorer!)
- change elements -- move, rotate, scale
- advanced position tracking (transforms)
- a proven track record
- and if you're artistic, you can use adobe Illustrator art in your game.

Answer (score 0):

you could use JQuery draggable and droppable with some animation to make it automatic ( or use CSS transition)